# do ssl certificate that validate only the domain owner remove the browser warnig message?

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate

I have a domain with my website and I would like to use a ssl certificate to encrypt the user data. I don't have a company so I am going to bye a certificate which validates only the owner of the website. Is this certificate sufficient to remove the annoying warning message shown by the browser when a user is accessing my web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need domain validated SSL certificate for your site like www.mysite.com. Company or legal papers is not required, only the domain owner is verified. Usually, verification is performed by modifying dns records or uploading a file to your web site.

You can get a free trial certificate valid for 30 days from symentec. https://trustcenter.websecurity.symantec.com/process/retail/trial_product_selector